# Problema con combinatoria en array de javascript

Tags: javascript, array

no estoy logrando armar una combinatoria de valores en javascript y necesito ayuda

Mi origen es 
[[1,A],[1,B],[2,D],[2,E],[3,T],[3,M], ........]

Lo que tengo que lograr de resultado es lo siguiente

["1A_2D", "1A_2E", "1B_2D", "1B_2E".......]

Vengo haciendo prueba tras pruebas, desde hacer un forEach dentro de otro, hasta hacer un group por el primer valor, para luego recorrer y combinar en base al segundo valor, pero vuelvo a la instancia de tener valores de mas, o no tener los valores necesarios como se espera en el resultado.

Ya no se me ocurre como recorrer el array para poder hacer esta combinatoria???

Logre llegar a lo que necesitaba, el unico problemas es que esta horrible

```
function combine(list) {
  var set = [],
    listSize = list.length,
    combinationsCount = 1 << listSize,
    combination;

  for (var i = 1; i < combinationsCount; i++) {
    var combination = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < listSize; j++) {
      if (i & (1 << j)) {
        combination.push(list[j]);
      }
    }
    set.push(combination);
  }

  var p = set.filter(function(item, idx) {
    return item.length == 2;
  });

  var flat = p.map(f => {
    return f.join("|")
  })

  var x = flat.filter(function(item, idx) {
    return item.split('|')[0].split('_')[0] !== item.split('|')[1].split('_')[0];
  });


  return x;
}
```

OUTPUT:

[
  "1_A|2_C",
  "1_Y|2_C",
  "1_A|2_J",
  "1_Y|2_J",
  "1_A|3_V",
  "1_Y|3_V",
  "2_C|3_V",
  "2_J|3_V",
  "1_A|3_T",
  "1_Y|3_T",
  "2_C|3_T",
  "2_J|3_T"
]

Gracias

**ACTUALIZO PREGUNTA.**

Legue a esta instancia

```
    function combine(list) {
  var combinatoria = new Array(1 << list.length)
    .fill()
    .map((e1, i) => list.filter((e2, j) => i & (1 << j)));


  var p = combinatoria.filter((item, idx) => {
    return item.length == list[list.length - 1][0];
  });

  var flat = p.map((f) => {
    return f.join("|");
  });

  console.log(flat)

  return x;
}
```

Logre obtener todas las combinatorias que necesito, pero me sobran algunas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo unico que me esta faltando, es poder eliminar las que estan de mas, deberia quedar en la columna 1, solo 1, la 2,solo 2, y las 3 solo 3, quedando de la siguiente forma

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola compañero o compañera @mpanichella te invito a hacer el [tour] para conocer acerca de stackoverflow en español, tambien te invito a que leas sobre [ask] en stackoverflow para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida y nosotros podamos ayudarte, así como esta la pregunta actualmente recomiendo que la edites y pongas aquello que haz intentado, de lo contrario puede terminar cerrada o puntuada negativamente por miembros de la comunidad.

Comment: Que bueno, te felicito por atender nuestras recomendaciones y editar la pregunta, sin embargo no es suficiente, para poder ayudarte debes poner código tuyo, debes partir de algo, por ejemplo darnos un ejemplo claro pero con codigo javascript en este caso debe ser código del lenguaje, una linea... dos o tres de código no son suficientes, debes partir de lo basico lo basico del lenguaje que te puede llevar a la solución del problema, por ejemplo consultar sobre como se hacen arreglos en javascript, como declararlos y como iterarlos, busca aquello, intenta realizar el problema y si.

Comment: y si aún no lo logras, ya almenos tendras un progreso, algo solido con lo que comenzar, con lo que te podemos ayudar, porque ya teniendo lo basico del problema, se podrán cometer errores, errores que te podemos explicar, y ayudar, no te doy la respuesta así por así porque de que vale?, la ídea del sitio es que los usuarios investiguen y pongan código concreto, código en el cuál nosotros podamos analizar el error o porque no funciona, no construir aquello, que te parece si investigas un poco mas y en un tiempo editas la pregunta de nuevo y pones esto que digo?

Comment: Si al final no lo logras aún entonces yo personalmente dare una respuesta con el fin de ayudarte aunque las reglas del sitio sean claras, no me importa recibir puntuación negativa por ayudarte.

Comment: El problema es que como generas las repuestas podría decir que en el ejemplo la posición 0 y 2 es una combinación y la 1-3 otra y así en el for sumando de dos en dos pero aún así creo que no es la respuesta

Comment: Genial camarada, tu pregunta ahora se ve excelente!, ahora se ve algo mas compleja, intentare ayudarte te di un voto arriba porque me resulta hasta interesante, pero primero, si, se que ya pusiste ilustracion e imagen del resultado que quieres, pero quiero aclararme un poco ya que pueden haber varias combinaciones... pregunta tecnica, la combinatoria no sigue un patron claro, pense que era ordenando los numeros y a la vez sus letras, pero en un momento dado se interrumpe este patron (el de la primera imagen) asi por que si, tu patron en que se basa?, es que aun no logro entender la combinacion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya que los requerimientos de la pregunta han cambiado procedo a añadir otra respuesta (basada en la original:

**La función esta dividida en tes bloques y dos formatos de retorno:**

1. **Acumulador:** Este consiste en un ciclado doble del array principal en el que se juntan los valores de los arrays hijos en crudo, por ejemplo si un hijo es `[1,"A"]` este será `"1A"` y se compara con su equivalente en sel segundo ciclo para solo retornar el par (un array) al acumulador si es diferente, esto quiere decir que `["1A","2A"]` pasará pero `["1A","1A"]` no.
2. **Formateado del acumulador:** Una vez listo el acumulador retornara un array bidimensional que es difícil de trabajar por lo que lo mapeamos para convertir los array hijos en objetos con el siguiente formato, si tenemos el array `["1A","2A"]` ahora será `{prefix:"1A",sufix:"2A"}` (a esto lo llamaremos el precompile).
3. **Compilado (o compresión):** Ahora hacemos un ciclado del precompile y dentro filtramos los prefixes en un array exterior, luego en el mismo ciclo verificamos si existe ya el prefix en la variable exterior para concatenar el sufix incidente al sufix de la variable exterior filtrada, esto quiere decir que si tenemos `{pre:"1A",su:"2D"}` y  `{pre:"1A",su:"3E"}` ahora sera `{pre:"1A",su:["2D","3E"]}`, básicamente mezclamos todos los prefixes en uno solo con todos su sufixes.

Ahora tenemos un array de objetos que combina todo con todo y esta ordenado por el numero de incidencias, ya podríamos dejarlo así para otros propósitos (como una mejor manipulación por ejemplo) y sería este un formato de retorno pero como quieres que sea un array plano, simplemente mapeamos el array para concatenar el prefijo con sus sufijos utilizando el antes ya mencionado join (en la respuesta anterior).

En el siguiente ejemplo puedes observar la consola para saber como retorna cada bloque y observes la evolución según esta vaya pasando (serían como los hooks de la función); y esta puede retornar de dos formas en variable var `myarray = flat(arr)`, o como callback:

```
flat(arr, ({flat, compiled}) => {
  console.log(flat, compiled)
})
```

**Mira el ejemplo**:

```js
const biarray = [[1,"A"],[1,"B"],[2,"D"],[2,"E"], [3,"D"],[3,"E"]]


function flat (arr, cb) {
  var acumulator = [];
  arr.forEach(f => {
    arr.forEach(g => {
      let fjoined = f.join("");
      let gjoined = g.join("");
      let pair = [];
      pair.push(fjoined, gjoined)
      if (f[0] !== g[0]) acumulator.push(pair)
    })
  })
  var unCompiledAcumulator = acumulator.map(a => {
    return {pre:a[0], post:a[1]}
  })

  console.log("Acumulator:", acumulator)
  console.log("Uncompiled", unCompiledAcumulator)

  let compiled = [];
  
  unCompiledAcumulator.forEach(a => {
    var exists = compiled.filter(x => {
      return x.pre == a.pre;
    })
    if (exists.length) {
      var existsIndex = compiled.indexOf(exists[0]);
      compiled[existsIndex].post = compiled[existsIndex].post.concat(a.post);
    } else {
    if (typeof a.post == 'string')
      var post = a.post;
      a.post = [];
      a.post.push(post)
      compiled.push(a);
    }
  })

  console.log("Compiled:", compiled)

  let flat = compiled.map(x => {
    return x.pre + "_" + x.post.join("_");
  })

  console.log("Flat:", flat)

  if (cb) return cb({flat, compiled})
  return flat
}

document.querySelector("pre").innerHTML += "  Flat: " + JSON.stringify(flat(biarray));

flat(biarray, ({compiled}) => {
  document.querySelector("pre").innerHTML += `
  
  Compiled:`+ JSON.stringify(compiled, null,2)
})
```

```html
<pre>
  
</pre>
```

> ***NOTA***: Para ver los hooks activa la consola o [corre el ejemplo en playcode](https://playcode.io/574698).

Espero que te sea de ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes [mapear](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map) el array y aplicar un [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/join) a los array hijos.

**EDIT**:
Me di cuenta de mi error y acomodándolo, sigo la misma lógica, solo que ahora lo encierro en un foreach para obtener cada item del array y luego mapeo el mismo array dentro retornando el valor deseado (solo si el valor inicial indicado en el parámetro de la función no es igual a la inicial del item), esto quiere decir que si por ejemplo el valor es de `f[0] es 1` siendo f el item perteneciente al primer loop y el valor inicial de la función es 1, este procederá a procesar el map, de lo contrario retornara el loop.

**Una vez en el map, la lógica es esta**: Ya que podemos comparar el valor actual del foreach con cada valor del map si el valor de g[0] siendo g el item del map, es diferente al valor f[0], retornará el item haciendo join de los arrays según el formato que queremos en este caso podría ser `1A_2D`. Esto nos dará un nuevo array con sus items transformados (fs) que filtraremos para eliminar los resultados que dieron null, y este lo concatenamos con la variable reservada para concatenar los arrays (mirar ejemplo).

Luego en la función retornamos la concatenación final y listo.

> **NOTAS**:

1. Se encerró todo en una función para retornar el array con el valor inicial que quieras, en este caso solo hay 1 y 2.
2. Se añadieron las funciones [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/forEach) y [concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/forEach)
3. Se agrego un acumulador para concatenarlo dentro de foreach y es el resultado final.

```js
const biarray = [[1,"A"],[1,"B"],[2,"D"],[2,"E"]]


function flat (initial) {
  var acumulator = [];
  biarray.forEach((f, i) => {
    if (!initial) initial = 1;
    if (f[0] != initial) return
    let fs = biarray.map(g => {
      return f[0] !== g[0] ? f.join("") + "_" + g.join("") : null;
    }).filter(x=>x)
    acumulator = acumulator.length > 0 ? acumulator.concat(fs) : fs
  })
  return acumulator
}

console.log(flat())
```

**EDIT 2**:

**Estandarizando la función**: Realmente no se para que fin necesitas trabajar tus arrays bidimencionales pero puedes volver la función mucho mas potente no solo indicando el valor de la inicial si no el index de este, mira este ejemplo con la función estandarizada (porque puedes usar el array que quieras) y mejorada:

```js
const biarray = [[1,"A"],[1,"B"],[2,"D"],[2,"E"]]


function flat (arr, initial, initialIndex) {
  var acumulator = [];
  arr.forEach(f => {
    initial = initial || 1;
    initialIndex = initialIndex || 0;
    if (f[initialIndex] != initial) return
    let fs = arr.map(g => {
      return f[initialIndex] !== g[initialIndex] ? f.join("") + "_" + g.join("") : null;
    }).filter(x=>x)
    acumulator = acumulator.length > 0 ? acumulator.concat(fs) : fs
  })
  return acumulator
}

document.querySelector("#pre1").innerHTML += "  DEFAULT => [" + flat(biarray)+"]";
document.querySelector("#pre2").innerHTML += "  2  => [" + flat(biarray, 2)+"]";
document.querySelector("#pre3").innerHTML += "  A,1  => [" + flat(biarray, "A", 1)+"]"
document.querySelector("#pre3").innerHTML += "</br>  B,1  => [" + flat(biarray, "B", 1)+"]"
```

```css
* {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

pre {
  background-color: #323232;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: monospace;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

h3 {
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #364147;
}
```

```html
<h3>
  Normalmente:
</h3>
<pre id="pre1">
  flat(biarray)
</pre>
<h3>
  Indicando solo el valor del prefix:
</h3>
<pre id="pre2">
  flat(biarray, 2)
</pre>
<h3>
  Indicando el valor del prefix y su posicion en el array child:
</h3>
<pre id="pre3">
  flat(biarray, "A", 1)
  flat(biarray, "B", 1)
</pre>
```

Espero que te sea de ayuda, y aunque hay suficiente contexto, siempre debes demostrar que estas intentando solucionar por tu cuenta y no solo decirlo, pero muy bien por seguir los consejos dados, bienvenido y un saludo.

Comment: como andas, gracias por tu respuesta!, es muy dificil de plasmar todo lo que probe en una pregunta, por eso no detalle tanto codigo. Tu ejemplo, tambien lo probe, pero no logra obtener lo que necesito. Si te fijas, las respuesta dada por el join es [ '1_A', '1_B', '2_D', '2_E' ],pero no me sumarisa la combinatoria, como puse en el ejemplo, ["1A_2D", "1A_2E", "1B_2D", "1B_2E"]

Comment: Listo @mpanichella edite la pregunta para que de el resultado deseado, espero que te ayude, si no entiendes algo me lo preguntas en un comentario, saludos.

Comment: como andas? veo que esta mucho mejor la funcion que armaste. Hice la prueba sobre la funcion y veo que con 2 valores funciona bien, pero probe sumarle un 3er valor y ya no me hace la combinacion sobre este [
    [ 1, 'A' ],
    [ 1, 'Y' ],
    [ 2, 'C' ],
    [ 2, 'J' ],
    [ 3, 'V' ],
    [ 3, 'T' ]
  ]

Comment: capas me explique mal, pero en caso de agregar un 3er valor deberia tener como resultado [
    '1A|2C|3G', .......
  ]
Si agrego un 4to valor, 
  [
    '1A|2C|3G|4P', .......
  ]

Comment: Mi resultado es acorde a la pregunta si no te sientes satisfecho siempre puedes editarla para que se entienda mejor que es lo que realmente quieres, en cuanto a eso, ya estaríamos hablando de algo mas complejo, parece fácil pero en realidad me imagino que ningún carácter se podría repetir por lo que podríamos estar hablando de generar cualquier infinidad de combinaciones posibles, ya que mi solución solo verifica el primer caracter y en base a eso devuelve el string.

Comment: [Mira este ejemplo](https://playcode.io/574698) que es el mismo pero modificado para trabajar con mas caracteres pero aun así solo filtra la primera posición de cada hijo, ya que filtrar cada combinación de matrices posible sería una monstruosidad y por su puesto no es lo que se entiende en tu pregunta.

Comment: si, te entiendo, ahi actualice la pregunta, creo que estoy muy cerca de resolverlo, como bien decis, lo que hice es hacer una combinatoria de todo x todo, ahora tengo que ver como filtrar las que me sobran